# kohana db select returning number of rows and not results

Tags: kohana

For some reason I am getting the number or rows and not the results I need.

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.*,
u.id,
u.username, 
p.profile_picture 
FROM messages t1
JOIN (SELECT from_id, MAX(date) date FROM messages GROUP BY from_id) t2
ON t1.from_id = t2.from_id AND t1.date = t2.date
LEFT JOIN
users u
ON
u.id = t1.from_id
LEFT JOIN
profiles p
ON
p.user_id = t1.from_id
";
```

$query = DB::query('Database::SELECT',$sql);

$messages = $query->execute();

echo Kohana::debug($messages); // for some reason getting number of rows here

The documentation says

> Specifying the type changes the returned result. When using
>   Database::SELECT, a Database_Query_Result will be returned.
>   Database::INSERT queries will return the insert id and number of rows.
>   For all other queries, the number of affected rows is returned.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$query = DB::query(Database::SELECT,$sql);`.

Notice the lack of quotes. You need to use the constant value.

Comment: WOW thanks now I feel pretty dumb . Thanks for helping me, its still a learning process